Multiple JSON Property name on property
I have a requirement in which I must have property that can bind it's value by "debtAmount" or "Amount"

I did try to have annotation from above, and it works for debtAmount but value won't bind using "amount"

I want to achieve one an optional binding for one property (either by amount or debtAmount)
The top answer for on this thread doesn't fit the maintainability requirement because eventually it will have additional properties that will require multiple name binding. So I don't want much additional private property for each public property.

@jason.kaisersmith thanks for notifiying.  I have updated the question

if you want multiple JSON properties during deserialization, you can use JsonConverter
public class NewAccountRequestJsonConverter : JsonConverter<NewAccountRequest>
{
    public override NewAccountRequest Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var newAccountRequest = new NewAccountRequest();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
                return newAccountRequest;

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
            {
                string propertyName = reader.GetString();

                if (propertyName == "amount" || propertyName == "debtAmount")
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    newAccountRequest.Amount = reader.GetDecimal();
                }
                else
                {
                    reader.Skip();
                }
            }
        }

        throw new JsonException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, NewAccountRequest value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WriteNumber("amount", value.Amount);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}

During Deserialize use this NewAccountRequestJsonConverter as options
 var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
 options.Converters.Add(new NewAccountRequestJsonConverter());

 var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<NewAccountRequest>(jsonString, options);


this is perfect solutioon

One approach, already presented is to put some mapping logic inside JsonConverter (inherit from it and override some logic).
Second approach, as I see, could be mapping both fields to their respective fields Amount and debtAmount and have some method to fetch that info based on both properties, something along those lines:
public static class Extensions
{
    public static decimal? GetAmount(this NewAccountRequest request) =>
        request.Ammount ?? request.DebtAmount;
}

You would need to make amount fields nullable, to detect when they're not provided at all. Or you can treat default value of 0 as "empty value", if 0 won't be valid number.

i'll go with the 1st approach, because eventually this class will have other properties.

@EdisonC this approach will not be affected by news propos, on converter you need to add additional logic for news props

That means if there are 25 new props means 25 additional right? If yes, that would be an issue in maintainablity
